# selenium/browsermob addheader not working (2.1.5)

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob

I have been scouring the interwebs for days on this and cant seem to find anything that actually works. I have seen a lot of questions/examples and none of them work for me.

Java 1.8,
Eclipse 4.7.3a, 
Selenium-server-standalone-3.1.2.0.jar, 
browsermob-core-2.1.5.jar

trying to be able to set a request header, I have tried like 15 different solutions and none of them work, a heck of a lot seem to be for old versions of everything.

Simple-ish setup,

```
private BrowserMobProxy proxy = null;
private Proxy seleniumProxy = null;
private DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
...
proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.setTrustAllServers(true); 
proxy.start();
proxy.addHeader("myheader", "myvalue");
seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
```

the add header function gives no error but doesn't seem to set the header, I go on to set up the driver and the test all works fine but the header is not being set.

Is this code correct? am I missing anything? could someone actually point me to a simple example that is for the versions I have running or please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is the proxy getting configured properly? Can you check that the traffic is indeed going through the proxy? Also is it `https` or `http` url? You should test both and see for which one it works

Comment: I will check the traffic, that is a great point, thanks.  The site is https, I am locked into that. i read something about allowing ssl but that seemed to be an old version. do I have to do anything in the new one to allow that? Thanks.

Comment: I debugged and looked at chrome network tab, it gives the remote address as my ip and the port as the one I picked  and via 1.1 browsermobproxy. so it seems to be routing thru the proxy. but I checked the same place and my header is not listed in there. are there not any extra steps I need to go thru to make it stick? I checked to make sure the capabilities were being set correctly, the header item shows up correctly and I also made sure the proxy was going into the chrome browser start. any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try with the http request?

Comment: So I went into debug mode, setting the same header and tried to go to http://www.bbc.com, when I stop it and look at F12 I do not see any headers again but I see the same information indicating it is going thru the proxy,

Comment: Are you checking response headers for your header?